# What is the difference between IO a and IO (a) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-theory

What is the difference between IO (a) and IO a in Haskell?

For instance:

`IO (String)` vs `IO String`

`IO (Int)` vs `IO Int`

Most books I've seen wrap a type in parentheses before putting it after IO, but it's not obvious to me whether these are the same thing or not.

Comment: I'd recommend to follow the common style: never put parentheses around single identifiers as in `(map)` or `(Int)`, in any expression or type context -- they are redundant and only add noise. Parentheses are still needed in `(+) x y`, `f (g x)`, `IO (Maybe Bool)`, for example. In `(f x) + (g y)` they are also redundant, but sometimes they can (arguably) add clarity. Still, there is no point in writing `(x)` -- you should avoid it. I'd hope books do not do that.

Comment: @chi yes. The only exception is when writing parameterised C-preprocessor macros - and that is only because the C preprocessor essentially bypasses Haskell syntax completely. (And arguably, such macros should always be written in Template Haskell instead, however honestly CPP is a lot easier for simple ones, particularly easier to learn.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference that would matter to the compiler.

Generally in Haskell, we like to avoid any unnecessary parentheses, so `IO String` is the preferred style. But of course you do need parens for e.g. `IO (Maybe Int)`.